# How do I tell Haskell what MArray to thaw to?

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a determinant computation that acts on an `MArray` and produces a scalar in the same monad,
here I've replaced it with `return $ fromInteger 1`.
So I have a pure determinant function that uses it like

```
det :: (Num e) => Array (Int, Int) e -> e
det a = runST $ (thaw a) >> (return $ fromInteger 1)
```

And I get an error that Haskell can't decide whether it should use `MArray (STUArray s) Bool (ST s)` or a bunch of other `STArray` variants and that I should put a type annotation, so I do

```
det :: (Num e) => Array (Int, Int) e -> e
det a = runST $ ((thaw a) :: (Num e) => ST s (STArray s (Int, Int) e)) >> (return $ fromInteger 1)
```

And I get

```
"Couldn't match type 'e1' with 'e'"
"'e1' is a rigid type variable bound by an expression type signature: (Num e1) => ST s1 (STArray s1 (Int, Int) e)"
"'e' is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for: det :: (Num e) => Array (Int, Int) e -> e"
"Expected type: ST s1 (STArray s1 (Int, Int) e1)"
  "Actual type: ST s1 (STArray s1 (Int, Int) e)"
"In the first argument of '(>>)', namely '((thaw a) :: (Num e) => ST s (STArray s (Int, Int) e))'"
```

It looks to me like there should not be two separate contexts for `e` because `thaw` is not like `fmap` where the contained type can go from `a` to `b`, for `thaw` the contained type is `e` in the argument and result.

Plus, if I specify `e` as `Double` and remove the Num constraints then it compiles just fine.

Finally, if I remove the type signature for the function, I get
`"Couldn't match expected type 'a0 (Int, Int) e' with actual type 'p' because type variable 'e' would escape its scope"` which doesn't make any sense because `s` and `e` have to be type variables, there's no other way to write that.

So how do I get Haskell to accept the instance of `MArray` I told it to `thaw` to or figure out by itself that it should use `STArray` since it is the only one that works for general `e`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
definition :: ... tyvar ...
definition = ... (expr :: ... tyvar ...) ...
```

The two mentions of `tyvar` do not reference the same thing. Rather, we have the rule that all type variables in all explicit types get `forall`ed:

```
definition :: forall tyvar. ... tyvar ...
definition = ... (expr :: forall tyvar. ... tyvar ...) ...
```

That is, type variables have no scope. When you wrote

```
thaw a :: ST s (STArray s (Int, Int) e) -- this is the "more correct" version of what you wrote
```

you actually wrote

```
thaw a :: forall e. ST s (STArray s (Int, Int) e)
```

You thus said "take this `Array` of element type `e` and convert it to an `STArray` of every element type". That's broken.

The Haskell 98 solution to this is to use an auxiliary function to bind the type `e` again:

```
thawST :: Array i e -> ST s (STArray s i e)
thawST x = thaw x

det a = runST $ thawST a >> return 1
```

Of course, `thawST` is just `thaw` with a restricted signature, so this also works (this solution is mildly less general):

```
det a = runST $ (thaw :: Array i e -> ST s (STArray s i e)) a >> return 1
```

If you're OK with language extensions, you can use `ExplicitForAll` and `ScopedTypeVariables`:

```
det :: forall e. Num e => Array (Int, Int) e -> e -- e will be bound in the definition
det a = runST $ (thaw a :: ST s (STArray s (Int, Int) e)) >> return 1
-- s is not in scope, gets implicitly foralled
-- e is in scope, refers to that variable
```

Or you can use `TypeApplications` instead of a signature

```
thaw :: (Ix i, IArray a e, MArray b e m) => a i e -> m (b i e)
-- so it takes type arguments in the order i(ndex) a(rray) e(lement) b(rray) m(onad)

det :: forall e. Num e => Array (Int, Int) e -> e
det a = runST $ thaw @_ @_ @_ @(STArray _) a >> return 1
-- _ means "infer this"
-- so we left the i, a, e, and m types to be inferred
-- and we specified that the result array was an STArray and left the state type inferred
-- the state type is currently unnamed: it's given to us by runST
-- but you need another type signature (runST (_ :: forall s. ST s <result>))
-- to actually reference it by name
-- therefore, we are forced to use _ and let it be inferred in the argument to thaw
```

Comment: Wow thank you!  I knew about the implicit `forall` but I never really thought about why it makes sense in `(->)` and `ST` but not in any old type signature, so I only would have had any chance of finding type annotating `thaw` instead of `thaw a`.  Is `ScopedTypeVariables` the preferred way to do this?  I'm using numeric prelude so I already have to have several language extensions, and `TypeApplications` is strange to me so I went with `ScopedTypeVariables`.